# toArray on Laravel collection drops a JSON-like array

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have a collection that correctly returns a column called "areas" as `[0, 4]` for example. When I run `toArray()` on the whole collection, everything is converted correctly, but `areas` now is just an empty array.

I tried casting it to array or something, but it always deletes it after `toArray()`. Is there any reason Laravel does that and is there a better way?

My query is just as follows:

```
$rows = User::where('id', 351)->with(
    'applicant'
)->get();
```

Then returning the values I see `$rows->applicant->areas` as `[0, 4]`.

But when I do `$rows->toArray`, `$rows->applicant->areas` is now just `array()`.

Comment: can you post your query?

Comment: It's just a simple get of the model and it's relation, but I've edited it in my comment. Will post anything else that could be needed.

Comment: Try this in your model    protected $casts = [
        'areas' => 'array', // Will convarted to (Array)
    ];

Comment: I did, tried casting it a while ago, but didn't work. Now after some playing around I managed to get it to work if I call directly `Applicant`, but not if I call `User->with(Applicant)`. In the latter case it's always empty after a `ToArray()`?